# How to find distance travelled by 'Humanoid-v2' agent after training?

Tags: xml, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I trained 'Humanoid-v2' (https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Humanoid-V1) to walk. The rewards goes up during training. But, I need one more performance matric that tells me **how far agent has travelled?**

There are 376 observations of this agent (https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Humanoid-V1). **Which values corresponds to position x, y, z mentioned in line 27 of the XML file of the agent**: https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/mujoco/assets/humanoid.xml#L27 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Let the initial position be (x1,y1,z1) and position after a step be (x2,y2,z2)
- The distance traveled by agent in a step would be as below:

> dist=tf.add(tf.squared_difference(x2,x1),tf.squared_difference(y2,y1),tf.squared_difference
>   (z2,z1))

- Sum up the distances in memory until the end of the episode

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Yes, I can do it. But, my question is out of those 376 observations, which one corresponds to x, y, z values.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Humanoid-V1 (I know, it's for Humanoid-v1, but the definition of states and actions seems to be unchanged), you can obtain the x-velocity and y-velocity of the ["root" joint](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/mujoco/assets/humanoid.xml#L29) with `state[22:24]` (assuming `state` is the 376-dim state vector and using Python's indexing convention).

Then you can use for example `np.cumsum` to accumulate the velocities to get the translations, or aggregate the norm of the velocities to get the length of the traveled trajectories.